# Office 365: How to setup pickup directory

Tags: exchange-server, smtpclient, office365

I need to setup a pickup directory in my Office 365 account. I am sending emails to client  and getting this error:

> Service not available, closing transmission channel

The server response was:

> 4.4.2 Message submission rate for this client has exceeded the configured limit**".

After search found Pickup directory solution [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9033815/message-submission-rate-for-this-client-has-exceeded-the-configured-limit).

Anyone knows how to setup pickup directory in office 365?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were using Exchange Server, you would use the following PowerShell cmdlet:

```
Set-TransportService <ServerIdentity> `
    -PickupDirectoryPath <LocalFilePath> `
    -PickupDirectoryMaxHeaderSize <Size>  `
    -PickupDirectoryMaxRecipientsPerMessage <Integer> `
    -PickupDirectoryMaxMessagesPerMinute <Integer>
```

However, since you mention Office 365, I assume you're using Exchange Online as your SMTP server. If this is the case, then you can't use the Pickup Directory solution, as this is not currently available in Exchange Online. (And even if the cmdlet were available, you wouldn't have access to a folder on the Exchange server itself.)

What you need to do is to throttle your application so that it doesn't attempt to send that many emails in a given amount of time. The current limit for Office 365 is 30 messages per minute (one every two seconds).

More information:

- [Configure the Pickup Directory and the Replay Directory](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb124549%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx)
- [Exchange Online Limits / Recipient and Sender Limits](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchange-online-limits.aspx#RecipientLimits)

Comment: Thanks Philippe . I have already added a delay of 3 seconds after every email and the issue is intermittent.Do you think I still need to increase the time ?

Comment: Is there anyone else in the same tenant sending emails, maybe? The thing is, Exchange Online is not a good option for sending more than the occasional email. For legitimate distribution high-volume email sending, there are several options out there, otherwise, you risk being marked as a spammer.

Comment: can you suggests any good ones specially the ones you have personally experienced.
My client has few email services which sends weekly reports to clients up to 1000 users

Comment: I have used MailChimp quite successfully.

Comment: Thanks I will surely try this solution in next month